# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'calWin'

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, module, tkinter

I'm in the process of making a TKinter app, and have begun using classes to structure my code. I want to keep things readable by not having everything in the same file, but get this error when i run the code in main_frontend.py: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'calWin'
Here's the code in main_frontend.py:

```
import windows
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class app(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        frame = windows.calWin(container, self)
        self.frames[windows.calWin] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(windows.calWin)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

win = app()
win.mainloop()
```

Here is the code in windows.py:

```
import passing
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class calWin(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        calVar = StringVar()
        calEnt = Entry(self, textvariable=calVar)
        calEnt.pack()
        calBut = Button(self, text='Calculate', command=lambda: passing.calPass(calVar.get(), calEnt, calLabel))
        calBut.pack()
        calLabel = Label(self)
        calLabel.pack()
```

And from passing.py:

```
import core

def calPass(gtin, calEnt, calLabel):
    if gtinValidate(gtin, 7):
        calLabel.configure(text='The Full GTIN Number Is '+core.calculate(gtin))
        calEnt.delete(0, END)
    else:
        calLabel.configure(text='GTIN Invalid')
```

And from core.py:

```
def calculate(gtin):
    '''
Calculates the check digit of a GTIN-8 number
    '''
    x = (int(gtin[0])+int(gtin[2])+int(gtin[4])+int(gtin[6]))*3
    x += int(gtin[1])+int(gtin[3])+int(gtin[5]) #Adds every other number in code
    remainder = x%10 #Finds how far check digit is away from nearest multiple of ten
    gtin = list(gtin)
    if remainder != 0:
        gtin.append(str(10-remainder))#Adds check digit to end of code if remainder is more than 0
    else:
        gtin.append('0')
    return(''.join(gtin))
```

And here is a detail of the error that I get when I run the code from main_frontend.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\PythonCode\Stock Control Task\Organised GTIN TKinter GUI Project\main_frontend.py", line 33, in <module>
    win = app()
  File "H:\PythonCode\Stock Control Task\Organised GTIN TKinter GUI Project\main_frontend.py", line 22, in __init__
    frame = windows.calWin(container, self)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'calWin'
```

Help?

Comment: Are you certain that the `windows` you are importing is the file you think it is? You can put `print(windows.__file__)` in your code to see what file is being imported.

Comment: Why are you passing `self` to `calWin`?

Comment: Yes I'm certain it's the same file because I tested it with windows.__doc__ and it printed the documentation I had on it. And I pass self to calWin because I'm declaring calWin to be an instance of the tk.Frame() class, so the parent of any widgets I want in there is in fact just itself so I put self.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do have `calWin` in `windows`, I'm guessing that your problem has to do with the bytecode already existing from an earlier import. The import statement first checks to see if the module has already been imported. If not, it then checks to see if the module has already been compiled. Try deleting the `windows.pyc` file. Or add `reload(windows)` after the `import windows` in your `main_frontend.py` file.

Comment: No, unfortunately not the problem :/ still the same error

Comment: The traceback makes it look like the line causing the error is the call  to the constructor, but the following line using the class itself as a key in your dict is suspicious. You'll never get a second key in that dict I think. Isolating the error to one of the two lines by commenting out, can you confirm which line causes the error?

Comment: I can confirm that it's the call to the constructor that is causing the error. When I comment out the following line I still get the same error and the same traceback :/ This is really weird

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just re-wrote everything in a separate directory and reinstalled Python and all seems to be working well, don't know what happened.